# Properly lock excel while writing

Tags: c#, excel

I have a program which I want to change certain cells' values in an excel with. This program will be used on several computers simultaneously, therefore I'm not sure what would be the best way to handle it properly.
Let's say I have this method that opens the excel file for edit.

```
private void writeExcel()
    {
        Excel.Application excelApp = null;
        Excel.Workbook excelBook = null;
        try
        {
            excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\ed0510\Desktop\SomeExcel.xlsx", ReadOnly: false, Password: "123");
            Excel.Worksheet workSheet = excelBook.Worksheets["SomeWorkSheet"];

            workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Something";
        }
        finally
        {
            if (excelApp != null)
            {
                if (excelBook != null)
                {
                    excelBook.Close(true);
                }

                excelApp.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
```

If this method was to be called at the same time (on different computers), would it result in errors? And if it did, how can I handle it?
I saw solutions with ReaderWriterLockSlim and Thread.Sleep but I'm not sure how to use them in my case or if it's the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Workbooks.Open` does have a `notify` parameter to indicate to wait until the file can be opened for read/write. It presents an interface to the user, so if your application is unattended, that probably isn't a good solution. In that case, I would set up a timer to retry after a short time period. The `Thread.Sleep` solution you mentioned is probably implementing something like that.

---

The documentation I could find about `Workbooks.Open` doesn't indicate what happens on error, e.g. if exceptions are generated or `null` is returned, so to be most compatible with your existing code, I went with generating exceptions and chose `FileLoadException` as a likely one to be thrown if the file can't be opened for write operations. You'll need to test and see what happens.

It might also be that `Workbooks.Open` returns `null` on failure, in which case you might need to check an error code to see if it's because the file is in read-only mode vs. file doesn't exist. You don't want to retry if the file doesn't exist.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

private void writeExcel()
{
    Excel.Application excelApp = null;
    Excel.Workbook excelBook = null;
    bool retry = false;
    try
    {
        excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\ed0510\Desktop\SomeExcel.xlsx", ReadOnly: false, Password: "123");
        Excel.Worksheet workSheet = excelBook.Worksheets["SomeWorkSheet"];

        workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Something";
    }
    catch (FileLoadException ex)
    {
        // TODO: output exception details to error log
        Log(ex);
        // Indicate to retry
        retry = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (excelApp != null)
        {
            if (excelBook != null)
            {
                excelBook.Close(true);
            }

            excelApp.Quit();
        }
    }
    // Failed and need to retry?
    if (retry)
    {
        // Wait a minute
        Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000);
        // Retry
        writeExcel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add this to my code? I think this'll work perfectly, I just don't really know how to implement it.

Comment: Please review revised response.

Comment: Thanks, I can work with this now! Didn't know you can call the same method inside its scoop, great!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this problem in the future, I later came across scenarios when the accepted answer didn't quite work how I wanted it to. Here is what I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

private void writeExcel()
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\ed0510\Desktop\SomeExcel.xlsx";

    if (IsExcelOpen(path))
    {
         throw new ExcelFileIsOpen();
    }
    Excel.Application excelApp = null;
    Excel.Workbook excelBook = null;
    bool retry = false;
    try
    {
        excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\ed0510\Desktop\SomeExcel.xlsx", ReadOnly: false, Password: "123");
        Excel.Worksheet workSheet = excelBook.Worksheets["SomeWorkSheet"];

        workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Something";
    }
    catch
    {
        ++numOfRetries;

        if (numOfRetries <= maxNumOfRetries)
        {
             retry = true;
        }
        else
        {
            numOfRetries = 0;
            saveFailed = true;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (excelApp != null)
        {
             if (excelBook != null)
             {
                  excelBook.Close(true);
             }

             excelApp.Quit();                
        }

        if (retry)
        {
             Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);

             retry = false;

             SavingIntoExcelHDT();
        }
}
```

As you can see, first I check if the excel is open, as the `FileLoadException` didn't always work how I wanted it. To check whether the excel is open, I use this method:

```
private bool IsExcelOpen(string path)
{
    FileStream fs = null;

    try
    {
        fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

        return false;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fs != null)
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is the best way to do this, but it works perfectly for me.